# Why does this definition returns a function?

Tags: f#

I found the following in the book `Expert F# 4.0, Fourth Edition`, by Don Syme, Adam Granicz, and Antonio Cisternino:

```
let generateStamp =
    let mutable count = 0
    (fun () -> count <- count + 1; count)
```

I could not understand why this code creates a function:

```
val generateStamp : (unit -> int)
```

It looks to me like its signature should be

```
val generateStamp : int
```

For example, the following code:

```
let gS =
    let mutable count = 0
    (printfn "%d" count; count)
```

creates an int value:

```
val gS : int = 0
```

As I understand it the code `(fun () -> count <- count + 1; count)` should first evaluate the lambda and then `count`. So the value of `generateStamp` should be just `count`, as it is in the definition of `gS`. What am I missing?

Comment: `fun x -> y` is a function literal--it creates a new function but doesn't evaluate it. In your code the newly-created function is the return value, so you're seeing the `generateStamp` value has the same type as that created function.

Comment: @Yawar - You are probably right, but I do not understand why the newly created function is the return value. Why isn't the return value an int, given that `count` was the last thing to be evaluated and F#, which has no `return` keyword, always returns the last thing evaluated?

Comment: See this great answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/42430195/20371

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In any block of F# code, the last expression in that block will be the value of that block. A block can be defined in one of two ways: by indentation, or with `;` between the block's expressions.

The expression `fun () -> other expressions here` creates a function. Since that's the last expression in the code block under `let generateStamp =`, that's the value that gets stored in `generateStamp`.

Your confusion is that you think that the expressions inside the `fun ()` are going to be evaluated immediately as part of the value of `generateStamp`, but they're not. They are defining the *body* of the anonymous function returned by the `fun ()` expression. You're absolutely right that inside that block of code, `count` is the last expression and so it's the thing returned by that function. But the `fun ()` expression *creates a function*, which will only evaluate its contents later when it is *called*. It does not evaluate its contents immediately.

By contrast, the expression `(printfn "%d" count; count)` is a block of code with two expressions in it. It is *not* a function, so it will be *immediately* evaluated. Its last expression is `count`, so the value of the code block `(printfn "%d" count; count)` is `count`. Since the `(printfn "%d" count; count)` block is being evaluated immediately, you can mentally replace it with `count`. And so the value of `gS` is `count`, whereas the value of `generateStamp` is a function that will *return* `count` when it's evaluated.

Comment: Hard to choose between two very clear answers. I had to choose one. One observation: the code would be clearer with the whole lambda body between parentheses: `fun () -> (count <- count + 1; count)`. On the other hand parentheses are not needed around this line of code or the one in the original version of the function.

Answer (score 3):

It's syntactic trickery. The last `; count` part is actually *part of the lambda*, not the next expression after it.

Here are some simplified examples to work through:

```
let x = 1; 2; 3      // x = 3

let f x = 1; 2; 3    // f is a function
let y = f 5          // y = 3, result of calling function "f"

let f = fun x -> 1; 2; 3  // Equivalent to the previous definition of "f"
let y = f 5               // y = 3, same as above

let f = 
  fun x -> 1; 2; 3        // Still equivalent
let y = f 5               // y = 3, same as above

let f = 
  let z = 5
  fun x -> 1; 2; 3        // Still equivalent
let y = f 5               // y = 3, same as above

// Your original example. See the similarity?
let generateStamp =
   let mutable count = 0
   fun () -> count <- count + 1; count
```

Now, if you wanted to have `count` be the return value of `generateStamp`, you'd need to put it either outside the parens or on the next line:

```
// The following two definitions will make "generateStamp" have type "int"
let generateStamp =
   let mutable count = 0
   (fun () -> count <- count + 1); count

let generateStamp =
   let mutable count = 0
   (fun () -> count <- count + 1)
   count
```